# What's the most efficient container for insertion from the back and removal from the front and back?

Tags: c++

In terms of runtime, what is the most efficient container for storing a large amount of data through the back and removing from the front or back?

Comment: Are you pointing to Linked list?

Comment: @thang, Insertion from the front, removal from the back. I want to know what `std::queue`'s been up to.

Answer (score 13):

A [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) or Double Ended Queue.

Unlike a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), it isn't guarenteed to be stored in contiguous memory. You should benchmark your particular need though, since the cache is becoming ever more important and general complexity statements less so; however, in this case, a `deque` is where I would start.

Comment: A lot also depends on how expensive it is to copy the elements.  Even with 10000 elements, an `std::vector<char>` might beat `std::deque<char>`, but it's much less likely for `std::vector<std::string>` vs. `std::deque<string>` (although that depends, in turn, on the implementation of `std::string`).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the implementation, the size of the container, the
types involved, and probably other things as well, so the only
real answer one can give is to measure.  `std::deque` was
designed for these types of operations, and for very large
containers with expensive to copy types, it will doubtlessly be
the fastest, but the one time I measured (with a container of up
to 8 `char`—small and cheap to copy), `std::vector beat`
std::deque` hands down.